# stunnel without client

Tags: linux, ssl, stunnel

Can stunnel server work without stunnel client? I mean can I write my own http server with only HTTP and add SSL support via Stunnel server? and clients will connect to stunnel server with they own client program using ssl? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; this is exactly [what stunnel is for](http://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html).

Comment: Is it correct understood, that a client should be able to connect to the stunnel server without caring about whether it is actually IS a stunnel server, an apache, an IIS or something else? So the stunnel server is not adding anything to the communication protocol which the client must take into account?

Comment: @StephanRyer: Yes. Although SSL/TLS is a complex protocol with lots of versions and options, so it is hard to guarantee any particular implementation will be indistinguishable from any other... But in theory, the answer to your question is "yes"

Comment: Thank you, Nemo, for answering my question even though the original thread is 5 years old :)